# how WhatsApp verify mobile phone number(read sms verification code directly )- iPhone

Tags: ios, sms

I am trying to develop a mobile verification system for my app that use a SMS verification code.
We know that iPhone applications can not read SMS data from inbox so I can not read sent SMS automatically from inbox BUT right now I installed whats app, I enter the mobile number, it shows a connecting page and send verified my app.

My question is that what whats app do? Did it reads an SMS automatically or using another scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find it. In some cases whatsapp do not use manually SMS verification.

In detailed, Whatsapp use SMS verification and require user to enter the SMS number manually ONLY AT FIRST TIME(same number in same device):

- If you install whatsapp and register with number A, whatsapp requires manually SMS verification.
- Now, if you uninstall and reinstall the app and also register with same number (A), in this case whats app do not use sms manually verification.

Maybe they are saving something in somewhere and if you use reinstall with same number in same device then it verify your phone in way other than SMS manually verification.

Comment: So there is no possible way to take OTP automatically in iOS (where as in android its possible).

Comment: No there is no way. we can not access SMS data programmatically

Comment: How does WhatsApp do this then? Do they have access to private iOS APIs?